# Magento2: I want to apply tax on specific products, not entire products

Tags: products, tax, magento2.3.2, tax-class

I am using Magento ver. 2.3.2 and I have configured the tax rules and tax rate in admin. Tax applied successfully on the products on cart page.

But now I want to apply tax on some specific products, not entire available products.

Can anyone help me in this, How can we do this?

Comment: i am not sure but you can make a custom product attribute and then you can use that attribute for the product to be selected for tax